# How to get the evaluation summary of the prediction if a separate test is used

Tags: java, weka, evaluation

I am trying evaluate the classification results with weka via java code. The code is as follows:

```
     fc.buildClassifier(train);

 for (int i = 0; i < test.numInstances(); i++) {
   double pred = fc.classifyInstance(test.instance(i));

    if(test.classAttribute().value((int) test.instance(i).classValue()).equals(test.classAttribute().value((int) pred))){
        System.out.println("ID: " + test.instance(i).value(0)+" -");
    }
    else{
       System.out.println("ID: " + test.instance(i).value(0)+" +");
    }
 }
```

When a cross validation is used this can be approached as :

```
     Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(data);
 Random rand = new Random(1);  // using seed = 1
 int folds = 10;
 eval.crossValidateModel(cls, data, folds, rand);
 System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString());
```

But if the testing achieved as the first code snippet how `toSummaryString` can be acquired?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using [`evaluateModel`](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable-3-8/weka/classifiers/evaluation/Evaluation.html) instead of `crossValidateModel`?

Comment: @nekomatic how this can be used with the mentioned code snippet? If you have an idea please post an answer to be selected. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use below lines.

```
Evaluation testEval = new Evaluation(trainInstances);
testEval.evaluateModel(Model, testInstances);
testEval.toSummaryString()
```

Detailed usage of Evaluation class for different scenarios can be found at https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=weka.classifiers.Evaluation